# Is it possible to get send data from a view to a controller without a form?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Suppose that I have the following:

```
<form action="shoecart" method="POST">
    <div class="flex-container" id="shoeslist">
        <h2>Your bag</h2>
        <div class="flex-container" id="individualitem">
            <img src="storage/pic1.png" alt="shoe picture">
            <p>name</p>
            <p>price</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to send src of the image and the paragraph contents to the Controller? If yes,
how do I send this data to any Controller so that it can add it to a table? As we can see that there are no inputs in the form.

Comment: You could use hidden input fields. You could also use AJAX to get the values and POST that way, would require some tinkering I suppose.

Comment: If you don't want to or can't use `input` fields, you can use JavaScript to get/read the [`src`](https://www.codespeedy.com/get-the-html-img-tag-src-attribute-value-in-javascript/) attribute value of your `img` element and the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) value of your `p` elements. You can then use `AJAX` to send that data to a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do it with the help of Ajax (javascript and jquery).

you need to fetch data(attribute and property) via id or class and pass data
on particular event using ajax to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot send the data like that. If you using ajax to submit the form, then you can bind the value there. if you do not want to show the input field, then use hidden input field. this could be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jquery`

for example you have thyis image `<img src="storage/pic1.png" alt="shoe picture">`

so add id attribute like this :

```
<img src="storage/pic1.png" alt="shoe picture" id="myImg">
```

so you can access this element in `jquery` like this : `$('#myImg')`

and you can send it to controller by `ajax`
but note you need to define this and add the image to `formData` and `append()` it before to send it to controller

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You would need to put those values into `input[type=hidden]` fields or you would send them via an async request (AJAX) using FormData.

*In short, you need to submit a form with the values that you want.*

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("img", "my_image_src");
formData.append("text", "my_paragraph_content");

let response = await fetch('my_endpoint_here', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData
});

console.log(await response.json());
```